# How to draw multiple images on canvas one by one like a slideshow with fade-in and fade-out animation

Tags: java, android, imageview, slideshow, android-canvas

i am developing a live wallpaper, i am new and stuck at this problem, can anyone tell me How to draw images on canvas one by one like a slideshow with fadein and fadeout animation.
i am able to perform this animations on views and layouts but i have no idea to run them on canvas. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you mean `java` or `javascript`

Some clues about fade-in solution:

```
var delta = 0;
var interval = 0;
var duration = 2000;

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
  ctx.drawImage(oldImage);

  ctx.globalAlpha = delta / duration;
  ctx.drawImage(nextImage);

  delta += interval;
}, interval);
```

- Consider using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of timers
- Calculate real delta using (new Date).getTime()
- Play with some easing equations - for example:

`alpha = Math.sin(0.5 * Math.PI * delta / duration)`